# R ncdf package - put.var.ncdf requiring incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, netcdf

I am organizing weather data into netCDF files in R. Everything goes fine until I try to populate the netcdf variables with data, because it is asking me to specify only one dimension for two-dimensional variables.

```
library(ncdf)
```

These are the dimension tags for the variables. Each variable uses the `Threshold` dimension and one of the other two dimensions.

```
th <- dim.def.ncdf("Threshold", "level", c(5,6,7,8,9,10,50,75,100))
rt <- dim.def.ncdf("RainMinimum", "cm", c(5, 10, 25))
wt <- dim.def.ncdf("WindMinimum", "m/s", c(18, 30, 50))
```

The variables are created in a loop, and there are a lot of them, so for the sake of easy understanding, in my example I'll only populate the list of variables with one variable.

```
vars <- list()
v1 <- var.def.ncdf("ARMM_rain", "percent", list(th, rt), -1, prec="double")
vars[[length(vars)+1]] <- v1
ncdata <- create.ncdf("composite.nc", vars)
```

I use another loop to extract data from different data files into a 9x3 data frame named `subframe` while iterating through the variables of the netcdf file with `varindex`. For the sake of reproducing, I'll give a  quick initialization for these values.

```
varindex <- 1
subframe <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=9, ncol=3, rep(.01, 27)))
```

The desired outcome from there is to populate each ncdf variable with the contents of `subframe`. The code to do so is:

```
for(x in 1:9) {
  for(y in 1:3) {
    value <- ifelse(is.na(subframe[x,y]), -1, subframe[x,y])
    put.var.ncdf(ncdata, varindex, value, start=c(x,y), count=1)
  }
}
```

The error message is:

```
Error in put.var.ncdf(ncdata, varindex, value, start = c(x, y), count = 1) : 
  'start' should specify 1 dims but actually specifies 2
```

tl;dr: I have defined two-dimensional variables using ncdf in R, I am trying to write data to them, but I am getting an error message because R believes they are single-dimensional variables instead.

Anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: which package are you using?

Comment: ncdf package, not ncdf4

Comment: Where does the function `subframe` come from?  Edit your question to include loading `ncdf` and whatever other pkgs are required to make this reproducible

Comment: I've edited it, you should be able to run the code now.